# XCode navigation - method list

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

When I type class or object name and press <kbd>Esc</kbd> I can see the list of all available methods:
[image: UIColor sample]

Is it possible to get this window with only current class methods, not inherited from parent? Some shortcut or other convenient way?

Comment: No, I don't think you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no option for doing that.

As an alternative, select the **Symbol Navigator tab** (<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>) in XCode, and choose a class.

It will show the methods & properties of that class only.

[image: Relevant methods]

Comment: Thanks! But is it possible to search class by name inside the Symbol Navigator?

Comment: @Avt: yes, there is a search bar below the table, you can search there

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot do this in the Xcode IDE.